# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

Tenho este código para inserir valores numa tabela:

```
conn.Open();
comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ArticleBarCode(Code, Code_Article, BarCode, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted)
                   VALUES (@code, @codearticle, @barcode, 1, @date, 1, @date, 0)";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", next);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codearticle", code);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", numbercode);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Mas quando executo dá-me este erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ArticleBarCode_Article". The conflict occurred in database
>   "CardozuGestDB", table "dbo.Article", column 'Code'.

Como posso resolver isto ?

Answer (score 5):

Bem, o erro diz que você está violando a `constraint` da chave estrangeira, inserindo um valor que não existe na tabela de referência. Em outras palavras, o valor que está passando para a coluna **Code** não existe na tabela **Article**.

Tem que ver seu modelo para dizer certamente qual é o campo, porque seu `insert` somente não diz exatamente. Se tiver dúvida do campo reveja a `contraint` FK_ArticleBarCode_Article.

Comment: Como posso resolver isso entao ?

Comment: inserindo valores que existam na tabela Article. valide os valores para ter certeza que é um valor existente